# What exactly is a linearized polynomial in field theory?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I read the wikipedia article on [Linearized polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearised_polynomial).

But I'm not sure the quite use-case of it.

Can anyone elaborate on it?

Comment: Can you explain better your question?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco what's linearized polynomial for? For example, when do we use that polynomial? Cryptography? Error Correcting? I dont know. I just want to know the application of it.

Comment: I have used the concept in [7 old answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A11619+%22linearized+polynomial%22). That may be a start? Anyway, there is a section of their theory in Lidl & Niederreiter. D. Goss's book *Arithmetic on Function Fields* has quite a bit more, but may run a bit deep (depending on your background). I first encountered when working with character sums related to quadratic forms (or, polynomials in characteristic two such that all the exponents has binary weight two).